# Why is this property not showing in the Properties Box?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, properties

I'm trying to follow [this information](http://bit.ly/N8CKrt) to create an address book program in wpf. I am actually using visual c# 2010, and just adapting as I go along. However, I've followed all instructions as closely as possible, and for some reason the `contact` property isn't showing up in the properties box when I have selected `MainWindow`.

The code I have follows:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "James",
            Email = "james@mail.com",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 111111"
        });
        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Email = "bob@mail.com",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 222222"
        });
        contacts.Add(new Contact()
        {
            Name = "Emma",
            Email = "emma@mail.com",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 333333"
        });
    }

    protected List<Contact>  contacts = new List<Contact>();

    public List<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get { return  contacts; }
        set {  contacts = value; }
    }

}
```

I don't know if this helps, but for some reason, if I click my listBox, select ItemSource>Binding>Element>Path>Items my VC# 2010 crashes. could my problems be all program errors, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you manually type in the property name, does it compile successfully?

Comment: this protype is for 4.0 .. are you sure that u use framework 4.0 ?

Comment: @silentfrost I don't understand what you mean. I have typed and copy/pasted from the source, both ways it builds with no errors. run it with no errors, but I just cannot get it to show the data, since the property isn't there for me to manipulate, even though the code is there.

Comment: @HarunAbi yes, I am using 4.0.

Comment: could you access properties of your Contact Class? Like Contact c = new Contact();  c.Name ?    sorry I edited... It must be Contact (I wrote Custom )

Comment: @HarunAbi where would I access it? where do I put c.Name? It doesn't seem to recognize me wanting to do that if I type it.

Comment: I meant that I am not sure you can use Contact class in MainWindow class.. Then I asked that.. You can create  an instance in MainWindow constructor and lets see you can access this class or not in another class.. because if you dont derive your class from protected class which is Customer, you cant access it.. Maybe you must chanange it as a public class ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have it appear in the properties window, add the [Browsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) attribute to it:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public List<Contact> contacts
{
    get { return this._contacts; }
    set { this._contacts = value; }
}
protected List<Contact> _contacts = new List<Contact>();
```

Comment: Browsable does nothing. Thanks for trying though!